# How to get list of direct dependencies in group of nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image: neo4j graph sample]
I am new to graph DBs and need help in writing Cypher query for a specific scenario.

I have a group of relationship, likeL

```
Node A -> Depends on -> Node B
Node B -> Depends on -> Node C
Node B -> Depends on -> Node D
Node C -> Depends on -> Node E
Node C -> Depends on -> Node F
Node D -> Depends on -> Node G
Node E -> Depends on -> Node H
Node E -> Depends on -> Node J
Node H -> Depends on -> Node I
```

I need direct dependencies from a list of nodes. Like, if I pass a list [Node A, Node B, Node D, Node E, Node H, Node I], it should return:

```
[[Node A, Node B, Node D], [Node E, Node H, Node I]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one for Cypher, let's assume your nodes have a label `Node` and the property storing `Node A` is named `name` :

```
MATCH p=(n:Node)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(dependency) 
WHERE n.name IN ['Node A', 'Node E']
RETURN [x IN nodes(p) | x.name] AS groups
```